# stacking two android fragments vertically

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am designing a  UI for a calculator, but I want to use different fragments for different parts of the UI displayed simultaneously. However I want stack fragments vertically in a relative layout.

[image]

Yet, I want the fragment1 size be set by the size of the controls and not hard-code some height. That way I can easily change the controls of fragment1 without worrying about its total height.

I tried a relative layout but I can't get fragment2 to be displayed below fragment1. Here's what I have tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/side_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        <!--this sort of sucks (don't want hadcode 100dp, I want the controls I put in here to resize this automatically.-->
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        class="com.guitarv.www.ndigitcalc.SidePanelFragment">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_panel"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/side_panel"
        class="com.guitarv.www.ndigitcalc.MainPanelFragment">
    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

any suggestions in how to make this work?

thx!

Comment: Use a vertical LinearLayout instead of the RelativeLayout.

Comment: `android:layout_height="match_parent"` is the problem, change to `wrapContent` or use `LinearLayout`